# Export React native component as AAR android library

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I have a react native component and I've wrapped it in an android library and exported it as AAR library, but every time I add this library to another existing android app it gives me this error

***"Unable to load script from assets 'index.android.bundle'. Make sure your bundle is packaged correctly or you're running a packager server."***

and here's my gradle file

```
project.ext.react = [
          // the name of the generated asset file containing your JS bundle
           bundleAssetName: "index.android.bundle",
                 ]

apply from: "../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"
```

Comment: https://github.com/ggsrivas/reactAndroidSDKDevApp/tree/master/mysdk this repo has a .aar library and it holds the bundle file.